# Performance of WAN-Replication in Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

How Hazelcast's WAN-Replication is impacted on variation of following parameters (Assume 2 Clusters, each cluster with 2 nodes) ?

1. Latency Delay between clusters
2. Batch size
3. Batch Maximum Delay

Any reference for Performance benchmarking numbers on Hazelcast's WAN-Replication would also help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a vague question, for the performance of WAN replication is indeed directly related to all 3 params you have mentioned but how it would affect the performance is totally dependent on the values of those 3 params.

Not sure what you meant by performance benchmarking either. I suggest you yourself try and benchmark the performance that suits your use case. There are always things that you can play with, to tune the performance further. Check out this guide, would be helpful: https://hazelcast.com/resources/hazelcast-deployment-operations-guide/